# Customize the list layout

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, admin-on-rest, react-admin

I'm using the rest-admin Framework.

I would like to change the layout of the lists, and add a custom component.

Currently the layout is:

[image: Actual Layout]

I want is to add a quick search component. And the filter panel show or hide it with an action.
Because I think you lose a lot of space on the screen by putting a quick search filter. My idea is to make better use of the blank space.

The next image would be the layou that I need:
[image: Custom List]

I'm based on Google analytic user administration UI:
[image: Google Analytic Example]

**My question is: Can I do this by reusing the list component of the framework without creating a new "List" component?**

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to implement your own `List` component. However, most of the `List` work is actually done by the `ListController` component from `ra-core` which we didn't get the time to document properly yet but it shouldn't be too difficult to implement. You can copy/paste the code from the `List` component and adjust it as you need.

Two things to note though:

1. Quick search is already doable with always on filters. So if you can live without your exact layout, that's the way to go. Check the demo source code for an example: https://marmelab.com/react-admin-demo/#/customers
2. We are investigating support of children as a function for some of the `ra-ui-material` components (`List` is one of them) to make this kind of customization easier

Comment: PS: Please don't post duplicates of your StackOverflow questions on the repository issues. It just make more work for us